# Работа с массивами js

Tags: javascript

Есть два массива с одинаковым количеством ячеек в каждом:

```
["3.00", "2.50", "4.00", 0.06, "15.00", 12.05, 12.05, 12.05, 12.05, 12.05, 12.05, 12.05, 12.05, 12.05, 12.05, 12.05]

["1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"]
```

Задача: Нужно перемножить ячейки (1ая с 1ой, 2ая со 2ой и так далее) и сложить весь полученный результат умножения используя javascript. Количество ячеек в массивах всегда одинаково, но может меняться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Только вот непонятно, при чём тут `jQuery`?

```
var a=[...],b=[...],i,s;
for(i=0,s=0;i<x.length;i++)
   s+=a[i]*b[i];
```

Сумма в переменной `s`.

Comment: На счет Jquery исправил. Сейчас протестирую код...